# How to minimize/hide app in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, hide, minimize

I want to minimize or hide my application after some time say 30sec if there is not any activity.I mean when the user starts my application and  don't do anything for 30sec then my app should hide.Is this achievable in windows phone 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible with WP7. The security model of this OS replaces various restrictions on what your application can do. I have a feeling that applications that 'hide' themselves would violate the security principles that guide the design of this OS.